# How to count matching blocks in a text file Groovy

Tags: file, text, groovy

Say I have a text file that looks like this (including the `filename    matches` part):

```
filename    matches
bugs.txt    5
bugs.txt    3
bugs.txt    12
fish.txt    4
fish.txt    67
birds.txt    34
```

etc...

I want to make a new text file, each line of which represents a single filename with the following information:  `filename, number of times filename appears, sum of matches`

so the first three lines would read :

```
bugs.txt    3    20
fish.txt    2    71
birds.txt   1    34
```

the first line of the original text file (which contains the text `filename /t matches` is making things hard for me.  Any advice?

Here's my code that doesn't quite do the trick (off by one errors...):

```
h = null
instances = 0
matches = 0

f.eachLine { line ->

String[] data = line.split (/\t/)

if (line =~ /filename.*/) {}

else {
    source = data[0]  

    if ( source == h) {
        instances ++
        matches = matches + data[9]
    }
    else {
        println h + '\t' + instances + '\t' + matches
        instances = 0   
        matches = 0
        h = source
    }    
} 
}
```

note:  the indices for data[] correspond to the actual text file I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problems with your code are:

- you're using `data[9]` when the matches are in column 1
- you skip updating instances and matches when `source == h`
- since you only `println` when the filename changes, you don't output the results for the last file

Here's a simpler implementation that accumulates the results in a map:

```
// this will store a map of filename -> list of matches
// e.g. ['bugs.txt': [5, 3, 12], ...]
def fileMatches = [:].withDefault{[]}

new File('file.txt').eachLine { line ->
    // skip the header line
    if (!(line =~ /filename.*/)) {
        def (source, matches) = line.split (/\t/)
        // append number of matches source's list
        fileMatches[source] << (matches as int)
    }
}
fileMatches.each { source, matches ->
    println "$source\t${matches.size()}\t${matches.sum()}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The actual file I'm using does have `matches` in column 10.  How would this change your `line.split (/\t/)` code?  If you don't mind, could you comment your code so I know what's going on?

Comment: To skip some columns, you can index split() like this: `def (source, matches) = line.split(/\t/)[0,9]`.

Comment: well that nails it. can you please tell me what the first line of your code is doing, and does `def (source, matches)` define those two variable at once?  So `fileMatches` is an array with two entries per index value?  I'm close to getting it but...

Comment: @blaughli That defines variables `source` and `matches`, and assigns the first element of `line.split(/\t/)` to `source`, and the second element to `matches`.  See ["multiple assignment" in the docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Multiple+Assignment)

Comment: The first line defines an empty map with a default value of an empty list instead of the usual `null`.  That allows the code to just append (`<<`) the first time for each new key.

Comment: Oh, ok!  And why not let it be `null`?  b/c that's not an int?  Why can't we append to `null`? why...

Comment: Appending to `null` results in a `NullPointerException`.  Start up groovyConsole and try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this (using dummy data)

```
// In reality, you can get this with:
// def text = new File( 'file.txt' ).text
def text = '''filename\tmatches
             |bugs.txt\t5
             |bugs.txt\t3
             |bugs.txt\t12
             |fish.txt\t4
             |fish.txt\t67
             |birds.txt\t34'''.stripMargin()

text.split( /\n|\r|\n\r|\r\n/ ).                                // split based on newline
     drop(1)*.                                                  // drop the header line
     split( /\t/ ).                                             // then split each of these by tab
     collect { [ it[ 0 ], it[ 1 ] as int ] }.                   // convert the second element to int
     groupBy { it[ 0 ] }.                                       // group into a map by filename
     collect { k, v -> [ k, v.size(), v*.getAt( 1 ).sum() ] }*. // then make a list of file,nfiles,sum
     join( '\t' ).                                              // join each of these into a string separated by tab
     each {                                                     // then print them out
       println it
     }
```

Obviously though, this loads the whole file into memory in one go...

Comment: That would only be around 5MB by my rough (probably over-estimate) estimate, so yeah, should be fine...  It also copes with files not being in order wheras your code relies on the fact that all `bugs.txt` files will be alongside each other with no other lines inbetween...

Comment: are all of those periods necessary?  and is `drop(1)*` a real groovy method?  i'm getting errors

Comment: Nice functional approach.  All those spreads and collects are a bit mind boggling :)

Comment: @blaughli Yes, they are needed as they follow on from each other (ie: `split( /\n|\r|\n\r|\r\n/ ).drop(1)...etc` I did it that way so I could comment it for you...  Drop was introduced in Groovy 1.8.1... What version are you running?

Comment: @ataylor Think I've been doing too much Clojure recently...everything looks like functions ;-)

Comment: I see, thanks for that.  So this is one huge line?  And functional programming...my only exposure was two weeks of Scheme...loved it but had to rebuild my engine instead:)

Comment: for the untrained eye, this is a little too much to digest, but once you take the time, it looks so elegant :) although I'll have to admit @ataylor 's answer is nice and concise as well.

Comment: I'm running 1.8.2.  I really want to see this work, but I'm getting an exception.  I have no idea where it is bc I put everything on one line...

Comment: I got it working, it's great.  You know, this actually makes sense, thanks so much for the comments.  Can you explain this part: `collect { k, v -> [ k, v.size(), v*.getAt( 1 ).sum() ] }*.`?  How does `v*.getAt( 1 ).sum()` work?

Comment: @blaughli `v*.getAt( 1 ).sum()` collects every second element in the list of values (which are like `[['fish.txt', 4], ['fish.txt',67]]`) to get a new list `[4,67]`.  It then sums this list to give `71` :-)

Comment: beautiful.  Why is it `v*.getAt..` and not `v.getAt...` ?  Something to do with a dynamic collection...?

Comment: @blaughli `v*.getAt( 1 )` (using the [spread dot operator](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-spread-dot-operator.html)) is shorthand for `v.collect { it[ 1 ] }`, so it gets the 2nd element from every element in the list, not just the second element of the list itself.  `[['a',1],['b',2]].getAt(1) == ['b',2]` wheras `[['a',1],['b',2]]*.getAt(1) == [1,2]`